# Правильное создание Intent в Android

Tags: java, android, activity

Здравствуйте! Ключевое слово `new` каждый раз создает новый инстанс в хипе, верно? Отсюда возник вопрос: а не растрачиваются ли ресурсы при такой схеме вызова нового `Activity` как в примере на [сайте](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

```
public void sendMessage(View view)
{ 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); 
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

т.е. мы каждый раз создаем новый инстанс класса `Intent`? А что будет с ранее созданным при предыдущем нажатии? Его заберет сборщик мусора? Или, может, повторно он не создастся, а будет использоваться ранее созданный?

Не правильней ли будет сделать так:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{ 
    private Intent intent; 
    ... 

    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    { 
        ... 

        intent = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class); 

        ... 
    } 

    ... 

    public void btnClick(View view) 
    { 
        startActivity(intent); 
    } 

    ... 
}
```

т.е. создать объект один раз в событии `onCreate`, а дальше вызывать его при нажатии на кнопку (например)

Прошу помочь разобраться, ну или отправить меня изучать основы создания экземпляров классов :)

Comment: Да, второй вариант правильный. Туториалы пишутся для демонстрации какой то конкретной особенности, они не учитывают оптимизацию и прочие такие вещи, так как тогда это будет не компактный пример кода по конкретному вопросу, а полноценный проект, публиковать который для каждого локального примера слишком громоздко. Правильной архитектуре всего приложения учатся по совсем другим туториалам

Comment: @pavlofff Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не вижу никакого смысла в вашем случае так делать. Сделаете вы объект полем класса, либо будите создавать локально это никак не скажется на производительности и затратам памяти, вряд ли пользователь заметит задержку в несколько миллисекунд, а то и меньше, которые потратятся на создание объекта. Так вы только раздуваете код ненужными переменными. Лучше создавайте `intent` через фабричный метод той активити, которую вы хотите запустить.

```
public class SecondActivity extend Activity {

    public static createIntent(Context context) {
        return new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
    }
}

private void someMetod(){
    startActivity(SecondActivity.createIntent(context));
}
```

Это даст вам преимущество, когда вы захотите передать параметры в новую активити, т.к. параметры устанавливаемые в `intent` будут в одном месте, что сократит время изменения кода.

Answer (score 2):

Существует шаблон проектирования [*Объектный пул*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BB). Он полезен, когда создание и/или уничтожение объекта занимает много времени, объекты создаётся часто, но существуют одновременно немного их них.

В Вашем случае, когда существует только один объект, всё так и сводится к хранению одного-единственного экземпляра. Отправиться учить можно и полезно паттерны проектирования, в частности, [порождающие шаблоны](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9E.D1.81.D0.BD.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BD.D1.8B.D0.B5).

Answer (score 2):

начните бурить [отсюда](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/59-urok-22-intent-intent-filter-context-teorija.html), и [тут](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html) тоже много интересной информации для Вас. А вообще изучите еще [flag intent](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/190-urok-116-povedenie-activity-v-task-intent-flagi-launchmode-affinity).

Например `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` – ищет в таске создаваемое `Activity`. Если находит, то открывает, а все, что выше – закрывает.